# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[231.49377550490459]'

Tags: python

I am trying to cast a python list into a float. 
This is the problem narrowed down:

```
loss = ['[228.55112815111235]', '[249.41649450361379]']
print(float(loss[0]))
```

And results in the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[231.49377550490459]'
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can't convert a list in a string to a float.

Comment: '[231.49377550490459]' is not a float inside of a string, '231.49377550490459' is

Comment: A better question might be: why are you getting the data in that format to begin with?

Comment: @PM2Ring I must have misread the tag, because it doesn't look like it was changed.

Answer (score 1):

Strip the brackets.

```
float(loss[0].replace('[', '').replace(']', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string slicing if there is always just one element in your string list.

```
loss = ['[228.55112815111235]', '[249.41649450361379]']
print(float(loss[0][1:-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `float` value is encapsulated within brackets. And you'll get `ValueError` because that is not valid float value. In order to convert it, you have to firstly remove them. For example:

```
>>> my_val = '[228.55112815111235]'
>>> print float(my_val[1:-1])
228.551128151
```

In your case, you have to write:

```
>>> loss = ['[228.55112815111235]', '[249.41649450361379]']
>>> float(loss[0][1:-1])
228.55112815111235
```

In case you want to convert entire list to list of `float`, you may use `map()` function as:

```
>>> map(lambda x: float(x[1:-1]), loss)
[228.55112815111235, 249.4164945036138]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the list values to floats you can use list comprehension:

```
loss = [float(loss[i][1:-1]) for i in range(len(loss))]
```

Then your loss list will look like this:

```
[228.55112815111235, 249.4164945036138]
```

Comment: Even better: `[float(i[1:-1]) for i in loss]`